# mdToast cannot resolve a promise with itself error

Tags: material-design, angular-material

I keep running into an error in the console when my $mdToast fires. It says: `TypeError: [$q:qcycle] Expected promise to be resolved with value other than itself '{}'` The toast works fine, but I would prefer not to have that error whenever it pops up. Here is the function:

```
let showSuccess = this.mdToast.show({
        template: '<md-toast>User added successfully!</md-toast>',
        hideDelay: 33000,
        position: 'top'
    });

    this.mdToast.hide(showSuccess);
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass toast itself to `hide` function. Just use it without any parameters:

```
this.mdToast.hide();
```

According to the [reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast#mdtoast-hide-response) it hides an existing toast. Optional *response* parameter is actually used for another purpose (promises).

> **$mdToast.hide([response]);**
>
> Hide an existing toast and resolve the promise returned from *$mdToast.show()*.